# Relation between angle subtended by object and number of pixels

Tags: android, image, image-processing, geometry

I am making a camera-based application for Android. My problem, is to find the real angle subtended by an object in an image, on the camera, when I have :

1.The length of that object in the image, in pixels,

2.The vertical angle-of-view of the camera,

3.The length of the image,in pixels.

Being new to image processing, I have this (probably basic) doubt. Is there a linear relationship between the angle that an object subtends on the camera, and the number of pixels in the image of the object taken by the camera? Angle subtended: Join the topmost point of the object to camera, then join bottom most point of object to camera. The angle formed at the camera, is the angle subtended. For example: Consider an image that is vertically, 200 pixels in height. The vertical angle of view of the camera, is suppose 20 degrees. So, I can say, that this 20 degrees covers 200 pixels of the image. Now, there is a portion of the image (an object) which is 10 pixels in height. I want to find the angle subtended by this object on the camera, in physical world. Would I be right in telling that, since 200 pixels are covered by 20 degrees, 10 pixels would be covered by 1 degree? That is, this object subtends an angle of 1 degree on the camera?.

[image]

As shown in this diagram, I know the values of L (of image), P (of object in image), x (Vertical angle of view of camera), and I want to find y , the angle subtended by object on camera. My assumption is (y/P)=(x/L), that is directly proportional. Would this assumption be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw horizontal line. It's length D is distance to object.

D * tg(X/2) = L/2

and

D * tg(Y/2) = P/2

so

Y = 2 * Arctg(tg(X/2) * P / L)

(When angles are small, they are (rough) direct proportional)

Addition: case of non-centered object.

[image]

P0, P1 - pixel coordinates of object ends relative to center point D

distance Dx = |**OD**| = L * ctg (X/2)

coordinate **D**=(Dx,0)

Y = Angle(**OP1, OP0**) = ArcCos((**OP1** x **OP0**)/(|**OP1**| * |**OP0**|)) , where x means scalar product

Y = ArcCos((Dx*Dx+P1*P0)/Sqrt((Dx*Dx+P1*P1)*(Dx*Dx+P0*P0)))

Example: 
L=L1-L0=768 pixels

X = 42 degrees

Dx = 1000 (rough)

P1 position = 100 pixels

P0 position = -50 pixels

Y = ArcCos((1000*1000-100*50)/(Sqrt((1000*1000 +100*100)*(1000*1000+50*50)))) = 7 degrees (rough)

Comment: Also, this only works if you assume that the object is centred vertically with respect to the optical axis (like in your diagram). IF not, then you need more information to calculate `y`.

Comment: Ok, when you say X/2 and Y/2 you are assuming that the horizontal line  bisects the angle. Yeah, that would be only true if the image is centered vertically, which it need not be. Actually, the symmetry in the above diagram, is just a coincidence. The object need not be vertically centered. So, when it is not centered vertically, what more data will I need, to compute Y?

Comment: Will image and object lie in the plane that perpendicular to optical axe?

Comment: Yes, they will lie in the same plane. The image is 2D, so everything in that image will be in same plane.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will do, puts me in the correct direction.

Comment: Isn't the result in your example 8.57 degrees?

Comment: @MBo      is it possible to calculate the angle between the human body and the camera. Could you please suggest me any references? I have the pose estimated coordinates for the human body. I would like to find the angle between the body and the camera.